# Angular Typescript add sum up groups of input text box numbers

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript, observable

I have an page that I am building in which the goal is for every several questions to have a totals input

Example

```
group1A   = 3
group1B   = 5
... etc..
group1Total = 8  (calculate on function call of each input or observable...
```

HTML Angular code

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid black; padding:10px">
  <div><strong>Group 1</strong></div>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <label>1. Are you Prone to Infection, colds, coughs, or flu ?.............................. </label>
    <input id="group1A" [(ngModel)]="group1A" name="group1A" style="width: 40px;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <label for="group1B">2. Do you have inflammation, Heat spots ?................................................. </label>
    <input id="group1B" [(ngModel)]="group1B" name="group1B" style="width: 40px;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <label for="group1C">3. Do you have specific pain ? ( printed, then list on Back)................... </label>
    <input id="group1C" [(ngModel)]="group1C" name="group1C" style="width: 40px;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <label for="group1D">4. Do you have swelling?..................................................................................... </label>
    <input id="group1D" [(ngModel)]="group1D" name="group1D" style="width: 40px;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <label for="group1E">5. Do you have pus, open sores, skin problems, mucus formation ?</label>
    <input id="group1E" [(ngModel)]="group1E" name="group1E" style="width: 40px;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
      <strong>Group 1  Total = {{group1A + group1B}}</strong>..................................................................................................... <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 50px;" id="group1" name="group1"> 
 </div>
</div>
```

I keep on seeing BAD examples of Typescript that instead of sum it treats it as string so instead of "8"  i would see  "35"

All the javascript and jquery stuff I do not want as this is Angular5/Typescript.

I would prefer to loop over each "group" as I am going to have 10 - 20 groups in which each group i name

group1A to group1E    with total input of   group1Total
then say 
group2A to group2E    with total input of   group2Total

This sort of code does not work ...

```
 <p>first number:<input type="number" [(ngModel)]='a'></p>
 <p>second number:<input type ="number" [(ngModel)]='b'></p>
 <h1>{{a + b}}</h1>

 export class AppComponent 
 { 
   a: number = 0; //set default value as 0
   b: number = 0;

 }
```

Comment: You say that your last code snippet "does not work". What do you mean? What result do you get with that code?

Comment: I want to use typescript to watch for input box changes and tally (sum) up the values into a group total box

Comment: And you don't get that with the last code snippet? What is the problem with that code?

Comment: well,  5 + 4 = 9     instead it shows   54  .     I wanted to have something listening in which each input text box ends up putting total input text box

Answer (score 0):

You can convert strings to numbers easily using vanilla javascript like this:

```
{{Number(a) + Number(b)}}
```

Comment: I want to use all Typescript and have loops that check for the value of each group input   group1A +  4 others    to show the total in a group1total box